# Porting Qt based application in Android

Tags: android, qt

I have developed a Qt based application and I want to port it to Android. Is there a way for me to do this?

I am working on Android Gingerbread.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [Necessitas](http://necessitas.kde.org/), that has a nice GUI to easily help you to create, build, debug and deploy Qt applications for Android.

> **What is Necessitas ?**
>
> Necessitas is the codename for the port of Qt on the Android Operating System and of the user-friendly Qt Creator Integration with Android,
>
> This project provides you Qt for the Android Operating System, and a first-class citizen IDE letting you manage, develop, deploy, run & debug your Qt Applications on Android Devices.

[Download Necessitas](http://sourceforge.net/projects/necessitas/files/)

[How to install Necessitas SDK](http://sourceforge.net/p/necessitas/wiki/How%20to%20install%20Necessitas%20SDK/)

---

**Related Reading:**

[Bringing Qt applications to Android – a quickstart video](http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2011/02/28/necessitas/)